# Removal of member aws accounts on AWS Organizations

Tags: amazon-web-services

I am currently logged in as root in AWS organizations, and I cannot delete the information connected with accounts. I am trying to delete everything at this point so I can get my AWS account back to some level of normalcy. I have been unsuccessful in deleting the organization as it requires the org to be empty.

I have the following hierarchy:

Root

- Security
- Audit (account)
- Log Archive (account)
- Management Account

I can't seem to delete these accounts, so I can move on with removing the org. I am receiving the following error while trying to delete the audit and log account:

> Account #123456789 could not be removed. Learn more about
> prerequisites for removing accounts from the organization.
>
> Audit (#123456789): ConstraintViolationException The member account
> must be configured with a valid payment method, such as a credit card.
> Sign in into that account to address this. Note that attempting to
> access this account in the same browser will end your current session.

Neither of these accounts has an email address, as they were created and meant to be fictitious accounts. Also note I have used AWS-Nuke at this point and assumed it would clear this all out. Sadly it did not.

My end goal is to delete the organization. Thanks!

Comment: contact aws support.

Comment: Are you saying that you're unable to access these accounts to add a payment method to them prior to removing them from the organization?

Comment: Let me start by answering the first part: how would I access these accounts? They are not real. I could create them in our Azure tenant and give them an email address, but as they were not setup with those addresses would they even work?

Comment: Also as a note, I have contacted AWS support, I have been stuck a few days and saw some similar folks on Reddit and other sites post about this - I didn't see resolution in those instances. My hope is whether via support or community that an answer will be available to others in my situation in the future.